# Comparing common genes and transcripts between Gencode and Refseq

Tags: gene, refseq, gencode

This is a very naive question - I am trying to compare and get the common lncRNA genes and transcripts between Gencode and Refseq from their gff files.

Since their gene_id, gene_names are different, is there a metric that I can use to compare to see if they share similar genes?
Or a conversion table that would convert one gene/transcript name format into another...

Thank you so much.

gencode.gff3

```
chr1    HAVANA  gene    29554   31109   .   +   .   ID=ENSG00000243485.5;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;gene_type=lncRNA;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;level=2;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=ncRNA_host;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2
chr1    HAVANA  transcript  29554   31097   .   +   .   ID=ENST00000473358.1;Parent=ENSG00000243485.5;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000473358.1;gene_type=lncRNA;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-202;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,dotter_confirmed,basic,Ensembl_canonical;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002840.1
chr1    HAVANA  exon    29554   30039   .   +   .   ID=exon:ENST00000473358.1:1;Parent=ENST00000473358.1;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000473358.1;gene_type=lncRNA;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-202;exon_number=1;exon_id=ENSE00001947070.1;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,dotter_confirmed,basic,Ensembl_canonical;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002840.1
chr1    HAVANA  exon    30564   30667   .   +   .   ID=exon:ENST00000473358.1:2;Parent=ENST00000473358.1;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000473358.1;gene_type=lncRNA;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-202;exon_number=2;exon_id=ENSE00001922571.1;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,dotter_confirmed,basic,Ensembl_canonical;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002840.1
chr1    HAVANA  exon    30976   31097   .   +   .   ID=exon:ENST00000473358.1:3;Parent=ENST00000473358.1;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000473358.1;gene_type=lncRNA;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-202;exon_number=3;exon_id=ENSE00001827679.1;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,dotter_confirmed,basic,Ensembl_canonical;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002840.1
chr1    HAVANA  transcript  30267   31109   .   +   .   ID=ENST00000469289.1;Parent=ENSG00000243485.5;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000469289.1;gene_type=lncRNA;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-201;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,basic;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002841.2
chr1    HAVANA  exon    30267   30667   .   +   .   ID=exon:ENST00000469289.1:1;Parent=ENST00000469289.1;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000469289.1;gene_type=lncRNA;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-201;exon_number=1;exon_id=ENSE00001841699.1;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,basic;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002841.2
chr1    HAVANA  exon    30976   31109   .   +   .   ID=exon:ENST00000469289.1:2;Parent=ENST00000469289.1;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000469289.1;gene_type=lncRNA;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-201;exon_number=2;exon_id=ENSE00001890064.1;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,basic;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002841.2
```

refseq.gff

```
chr1    RefSeq  region  1       248956422       .       +       .       ID=NC_000001.11:1..248956422;Dbxref=taxon:9606;Name=1;chromosome=1;gbkey=Src;genome=chromosome;mol_type=genomic DNA
chr1    Gnomon  lnc_RNA 29774   35418   .   +   .   ID=rna-XR_007065314.1;Parent=gene-MIR1302-2HG;Dbxref=GeneID:107985730,Genbank:XR_007065314.1,HGNC:HGNC:52482;Name=XR_007065314.1;gbkey=ncRNA;gene=MIR1302-2HG;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 1 mRNA%2C 5 ESTs%2C 10 long SRA reads%2C and 96%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 4 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=MIR1302-2 host gene;transcript_id=XR_007065314.1
chr1    BestRefSeq  lnc_RNA 34611   36081   .   -   .   ID=rna-NR_026818.1;Parent=gene-FAM138A;Dbxref=GeneID:645520,Genbank:NR_026818.1,HGNC:HGNC:32334;Name=NR_026818.1;gbkey=ncRNA;gene=FAM138A;product=family with sequence similarity 138 member A;transcript_id=NR_026818.1
chr1    Gnomon  lnc_RNA 95222   107727  .   +   .   ID=rna-XR_007065337.1;Parent=gene-LOC124903816;Dbxref=GeneID:124903816,Genbank:XR_007065337.1;Name=XR_007065337.1;experiment=COORDINATES: polyA evidence [ECO:0006239];gbkey=ncRNA;gene=LOC124903816;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 1 EST%2C 8 long SRA reads%2C and 84%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 2 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=uncharacterized LOC124903816%2C transcript variant X1;transcript_id=XR_007065337.1
chr1    Gnomon  lnc_RNA 95222   107727  .   +   .   ID=rna-XR_007065338.1;Parent=gene-LOC124903816;Dbxref=GeneID:124903816,Genbank:XR_007065338.1;Name=XR_007065338.1;experiment=COORDINATES: polyA evidence [ECO:0006239];gbkey=ncRNA;gene=LOC124903816;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 1 EST%2C 8 long SRA reads%2C and 84%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 2 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=uncharacterized LOC124903816%2C transcript variant X2;transcript_id=XR_007065338.1
chr1    Gnomon  lnc_RNA 120849  175246  .   -   .   ID=rna-XR_001737579.3;Parent=gene-LOC124900384;Dbxref=GeneID:124900384,Genbank:XR_001737579.3;Name=XR_001737579.3;gbkey=ncRNA;gene=LOC124900384;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 5 long SRA reads%2C and 78%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 34 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=uncharacterized LOC124900384%2C transcript variant X13;transcript_id=XR_001737579.3
chr1    Gnomon  lnc_RNA 146300  175246  .   -   .   ID=rna-XR_007065328.1;Parent=gene-LOC124900384;Dbxref=GeneID:124900384,Genbank:XR_007065328.1;Name=XR_007065328.1;gbkey=ncRNA;gene=LOC124900384;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 4 ESTs%2C 24 long SRA reads%2C and 76%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 19 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=uncharacterized LOC124900384%2C transcript variant X9;transcript_id=XR_007065328.1
chr1    Gnomon  lnc_RNA 146301  175246  .   -   .   ID=rna-XR_007065325.1;Parent=gene-LOC124900384;Dbxref=GeneID:124900384,Genbank:XR_007065325.1;Name=XR_007065325.1;gbkey=ncRNA;gene=LOC124900384;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 4 ESTs%2C 25 long SRA reads%2C and 78%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 14 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=uncharacterized LOC124900384%2C transcript variant X6;transcript_id=XR_007065325.1
chr1    Gnomon  lnc_RNA 146435  175246  .   -   .   ID=rna-XR_007065330.1;Parent=gene-LOC124900384;Dbxref=GeneID:124900384,Genbank:XR_007065330.1;Name=XR_007065330.1;gbkey=ncRNA;gene=LOC124900384;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 1 EST%2C 25 long SRA reads%2C and 75%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 58 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=uncharacterized LOC124900384%2C transcript variant X11;transcript_id=XR_007065330.1
chr1    Gnomon  lnc_RNA 146470  175246  .   -   .   ID=rna-XR_007065322.1;Parent=gene-LOC124900384;Dbxref=GeneID:124900384,Genbank:XR_007065322.1;Name=XR_007065322.1;gbkey=ncRNA;gene=LOC124900384;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 4 ESTs%2C 24 long SRA reads%2C and 76%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 43 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=uncharacterized LOC124900384%2C transcript variant X3;transcript_id=XR_007065322.1
chr1    Gnomon  lnc_RNA 149034  175246  .   -   .   ID=rna-XR_007065324.1;Parent=gene-LOC124900384;Dbxref=GeneID:124900384,Genbank:XR_007065324.1;Name=XR_007065324.1;gbkey=ncRNA;gene=LOC124900384;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 4 ESTs%2C 25 long SRA reads%2C and 78%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 17 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=uncharacterized LOC124900384%2C transcript variant X5;transcript_id=XR_007065324.1
chr1    Gnomon  lnc_RNA 149035  175246  .   -   .   ID=rna-XR_007065331.1;Parent=gene-LOC124900384;Dbxref=GeneID:124900384,Genbank:XR_007065331.1;Name=XR_007065331.1;gbkey=ncRNA;gene=LOC124900384;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 1 EST%2C 24 long SRA reads%2C and 76%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 38 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=uncharacterized LOC124900384%2C transcript variant X12;transcript_id=XR_007065331.1
chr1    Gnomon  lnc_RNA 149035  175246  .   -   .   ID=rna-XR_007065327.1;Parent=gene-LOC124900384;Dbxref=GeneID:124900384,Genbank:XR_007065327.1;Name=XR_007065327.1;gbkey=ncRNA;gene=LOC124900384;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 4 ESTs%2C 24 long SRA reads%2C and 76%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 33 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=uncharacterized LOC124900384%2C transcript variant X8;transcript_id=XR_007065327.1
chr1    Gnomon  lnc_RNA 151857  175246  .   -   .   ID=rna-XR_007065323.1;Parent=gene-LOC124900384;Dbxref=GeneID:124900384,Genbank:XR_007065323.1;Name=XR_007065323.1;gbkey=ncRNA;gene=LOC124900384;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 4 ESTs%2C 25 long SRA reads%2C and 81%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 5 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=uncharacterized LOC124900384%2C transcript variant X4;transcript_id=XR_007065323.1
```